# Unwind parallel arrays and format the response as key value pair

Tags: python, mongodb

I'am a newbie in mongodb and ipython.
I have a dataset like below:

```
book1 = {
"author" :"A A",
"book" : {
    "series" : "19 A, 19 B, 19 C",
    "year" : "1990, 1991, 1992"
}}


book2 = {
"author" :"B B",
"book" : {
    "series" : "20 A, 20 B, 19 C",
    "year" : "1995, 1995, 1992"
} }
book3 = {
"author" :"C C",
"book" : {
    "series" : "19 A, 19 B, 19 C",
    "year" : "1990, 1991, 1992"
} }
```

These data were inserted into mongodb.
I want to split series and year, because the first column of series was published in the year which is in the first column of year (maybe terms "column" is not suitable for this data because series and year are not array, but text) :

```
{"_id": {series: 19 A}, "year": "1990"}
{"_id": {series: 19 B}, "year": "1991"}
{"_id": {series: 19 C}, "year": "1992"}
{"_id": {series: 20 A}, "year": "1995"}
{"_id": {series: 20 B}, "year": "1995"}
```

I want it prints documents as shown above. Series is unique.

What I've done so far is like the code below. The idea is to split the text (series and year), then unwind them. But I am confused how to create the list as shown above. But this code return error and I don't have idea how to solve it.

```
project = {"$project": {"series_list" : {"$split" : ["book.series", ", "]}, 
{"year_list" : {"$split" : ["book.year", ", "]} }} 
}
unwind = {"$unwind" : "$series_list", "$year_list" }
group = {"$group" : {"_id": {"series": "$series_list"}}, "year":"$year_list"}
cur = db.collection.aggregate([project, unwind, group])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4 mongo version.

The idea is to [`$zip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) together series and year array with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to create a array of document with series and year key value pair followed by [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) & [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to create unique combination.

[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to promote the id to the top level

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "series_and_year_list": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$zip": {
              "inputs": [
                {
                  "$split": [
                    "$book.series",
                    ", "
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$split": [
                    "$book.year",
                    ", "
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "as": "zipped",
          "in": {
            "series": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$$zipped",
                0
              ]
            },
            "year": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$$zipped",
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$series_and_year_list"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "series": "$series_and_year_list.series",
        "year": "$series_and_year_list.year"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
book1 = {
"author" :"A A",
"book" : {
    "series" : "19 A, 19 B, 19 C",
    "year" : "1990, 1991, 1992"
}}


book2 = {
"author" :"B B",
"book" : {
    "series" : "20 A, 20 B, 19 C",
    "year" : "1995, 1995, 1992"
} }
book3 = {
"author" :"C C",
"book" : {
    "series" : "19 A, 19 B, 19 C",
    "year" : "1990, 1991, 1992"
} }

book_list=[book1,book2,book3]
for i in book_list:
    series_book = []
    b_list={}

    for key,value in i['book'].items():

        series_book.append([kk.strip() for kk in value.split(',')])

    for i in range(0,len(series_book),2):
        zipped_stuff=list(zip(*series_book[i:i+2]))
        for i in zipped_stuff:
            b_list["year"] = i[1]
            b_list["_id"]={'series': i[0]}


            print(b_list)
```

output:

```
{'_id': {'series': '19 A'}, 'year': '1990'}
{'_id': {'series': '19 B'}, 'year': '1991'}
{'_id': {'series': '19 C'}, 'year': '1992'}
{'_id': {'series': '20 A'}, 'year': '1995'}
{'_id': {'series': '20 B'}, 'year': '1995'}
{'_id': {'series': '19 C'}, 'year': '1992'}
{'_id': {'series': '19 A'}, 'year': '1990'}
{'_id': {'series': '19 B'}, 'year': '1991'}
{'_id': {'series': '19 C'}, 'year': '1992'}
```

Comment: Hi Ayodhyankit Paul. Thank you for trying to help me. I appreciate that. But the data were inserted, and I want to aggregate them, in order to print them like in the list that you made.